# What is the most neutral font?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, resource-recommendations, branding, typefaces

I create brand names and to evaluate them properly I must not be influenced by the typeface they are written with.
Therefore I'm looking for the most neutral possible font. I don't know if it would be a specific font that is known to be neutral, or if it would be one of the most commonly used that I see everyday.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Even considering the absolute base differences among typefaces..... serif or sans serif..... even that *will* sway perception.

Comment: I think that is subjective. But maybe you can train *your* eyes to seeing one font as neutral. When I want to write something and focus on the content and not the style, I write in a simple text editor with something like *Courier New* or *Consolas*. I'm used to seeing mono space fonts as "code" or "plain text".

Comment: This is somewhat subjective, but the most commonly used fonts are probably Helvetica/Arial or Times.  They are as plain as plain could be.

Comment: Every font recommendation is subjective, so why do you have a tag for it if you're going to vote it down ?!

Comment: I didn't vote it down. FYI. Do not make accusations here. People are free to downvote questions if they think a question is too subjective.

Comment: @BillyKerr I strongly disagree. Times and Arial are very non-neutral to at least my eye, because they make glaringly obvious that the creator didn't consciously choose a typeface, and thus give the work a very amateur look.

Comment: @Vincent - that's what I mean - it's subjective. You think they're not neutral, I think they are. I don't really care how strongly you feel about it. I feel just as strongly that they are neutral because of their ubiquity.

Comment: Didn't down vote, but probably should.... The subjective aspect of this question is **not** the request for a font... it's the request for "neutral". What **you** perceive can not be answered here by someone else. May as well ask "What color do I like most?"

Comment: @Scott - This question is like asking what's the most neutral ice cream flavour. Some will argue it's vanilla because it's perceived as plain, although technically it's a pretty strong flavour. Its ubiquity is what makes it appear plain (or boring) to those who eat it often.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very subjective question, but you'll be safe with using something very generic like.. plain old Arial, or Roboto from Google Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to separate a name from its visual appearance. ASCII numbers, Braille and Morse code deliver. I think the idea to discard the visual side is not good because people read business names as whole, they are images. You'll throw away a great part of the available information. Besides with non-visual codes you'll develop some replacement for the visual look, say the rhythm of the word as Morse.

My recommendation: Watch a name with various widely used simple fonts. If one looks acceptable, the name is acceptable.

Not asked: Some attention needs also how the name sounds as spoken.

ADD due the comments:

Get Scanahand or other "handwriting to font converter" and make your own font. The job takes less than half a hour and needs no experience. I guess there's no better way to keep foreign decisions off.

Comment: You misunderstood the question and assumed I have poor knowledge of branding. The font I'm looking for is for me to evaluate the names, it is not to identify the brand.

Comment: What qualities of the names you want to be observable? I guess there's no such thing as a neutral font. Because you call it neutral it must have something which is a property and it's observable at the same time as the ordered set of character codes which are presented as characters.

Comment: I want to observe the non graphic qualities.

Comment: You can let a speech synthesizer to read the names letter by letter. Then no visual property of the written appearance of the names will disturb the obsevations. I guess a person who has been blind his whole life doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @WaterBearer, I totally understand what you are looking for and why, but it *is* self-contradicting in a mind tickling way to want to *observe* something *non graphic*. Maybe it's not possible to separate written words from their appearance. It has melted together.

Comment: @user287001 this is not practicable, I have a spreadsheet with 200 names and 30 criteria for each, so I need to see the names without caring about how they look.

Comment: 30 well described criterias - are they so well described that a computer programmer could implement an automate?

Comment: @user287001 possibly, but I'm looking for a font, not a programmer.

Comment: @Wolff _observe_ is used in its wide meaning, in fact I analyse the words.

Comment: Then get the font you read with least errors. If the criterias are independent of opinions there's no other problem than reliable reading.

Comment: They cannot be independent if they are influenced. And they are not independent from opinion, it is art.

Answer (score 0):

A simple search for "most neutral font" revealed that there is a font that was designed for the purpose of being more neutral than the common sans serif fonts, by averaging all their characteristics.
This font is named [Neutral](https://www.typotheque.com/fonts/neutral/about), by Kai Bernau.

Comment: I still think this is *highly* subjective. Simply put, a sans serif can **never** be "neutral" because it is the antithesis of a serif font and carries with it connotations which are the polar opposite of serifs. So merely looking at the omission of serifs makes that font *not* neutral. Massimo Vignelli only used Helvetica because of the connotations he felt it provided. Sans serifs *do* alter perception.